# Audio .MP3 not working in Safari browser

Tags: audio, safari

I am developing `web application` where i have to use play sound where i used `.MP3` but its issue occur.

Sound `play good in chrome, Firefox` but in `safari its not working.`

```
<audio id="myAudio"><source src="/assets/noti.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
```

I have no idea and did not find anywhere so I asked here.

Hope and waiting for your response.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had also problems with mp3 file on safari and after a lot of research it was problem with the compression of the file.

Comment: Thanks @the scion for response. I will sure check with proper .mp3 file

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I had urls like `/listen/123`.
Notice that it has no extension.
I was streaming the file, so the link worked in chrome + firefox.

So I've added an extension to the url (`listen/123.mp3`) and modified my back-end code so that `123.mp3` would actually load the resource `123`.

And it worked.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem and I was able fix the corrupted mp3 file with the open source tool [MP3val](http://mp3val.sourceforge.net/). The problem which this tool fixed was "Garbage at the beginning" of the file. Now the sound works also on Safari.